# Setting a function equal a variable?

Tags: php

I have a PHP function and I want it to equal a variable. Here is the code:

```
 <?php       
 function ItsaFunction(){
    //Code goes here
 }
 ?>
```

I want to take that function and set it equals to a variable. How can I do that. Here is the code:

```
 <? ItsaFunction() = $ItsaFunction; ?>
```

The code above will not work but that is what I want to make. How can I make a php function equal variable?

Comment: What on earth does that mean?

Comment: You told us what you want, but not what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: That is never going to work. A function is by it's definition something completely else than a variable. These two can never be equal. I think you're trying to accomplish something else. Tell us.

Comment: Just pass a variable into the function `ItsaFunction($var)` and have it set a global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a function equal a variable, but how about a variable that equals a function?

```
$ItsaFunction = function() {
    //Code goes here
};
```

You could also do

```
function ItsaFunction() {
    //Code goes here
}

$ItsaFunction = ItsaFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() {
    echo "In foo()<br />\n";
}

$func = 'foo';
$func();        // This calls foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what to mean you want to check if there is a match in variables.

```
<?php  

 $letter = 'a';
 $word = 'a';

 function ItsaFunction($first, $sec){

if($first == $sec){

echo 'match';

}else{
//do something
}

ItsaFunction($letter,$word);

}
?>
```