# How can I create a function out my php select?

Tags: php

How can I create a function out of my php select? Here is the code:

```
<?      
$sql = "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE name = 'website_name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
?>            

<?=$row['value'];?>
```

Basically I want to turn it into a function and call it as a variable so something like this. Here is the code:

```
<?
function ItsaFunction() {
//code goes here
}
?>
```

I want to output the code as a variable. Here is the code:

```
<?=$ItsaFunction?>
```

How can I convert my select to a function and call it as a variable?

Comment: So you've opened a new account to ask the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517418/setting-a-function-equal-a-variable

Comment: What is `<?=` ? And why don't you just put the code in the function and call it ?

Comment: @Bun that's exactly what he seems not to know, how to do that. and <?= is one of the incarnations of short tags, something that should be avoided ...

Comment: @PatomaS Oh, did not know you could have an `=` in short tags... And I won't explain functions on here, so he better go read some docs :P

Comment: agreed, it has to read/practice some more, hopefully, will get some correct examples here to start with. And the use of short tags has almost disappeared, the standard configuration for PHP on the last, may be 8 to 10 years, hast it turned off on most distributions and packages

Answer (score 0):

So you want...

```
<?php      
function ItsaFunction() {
   $sql = "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE name = 'website_name'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
   return $row['value'];
}
?>
```

And then use

```
<?=ItsaFunction()?>
```

?

Comment: Basically I can not figure out how to output it from a function the code...

Comment: you use return for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function yourfunc($sitename)
{
$sitename = mysql_real_escape_string($sitename);
$sql = "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE name = '$sitename'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
return $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: How would I call the function above?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple transformation of your code to a function so you can call it. But you should do a bit more with that code, like check for results, initialize variables, etc ...

```
function get_website( $website_name = false ) {
    if ( $website_name === false ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT value FROM configuration WHERE name = $website_name";
        $result = mysql_query( $sql );
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ); // assuming you have results on row
        return $row.
    }
}
```

You will call that function this way

```
$website_information = get_website( 'name_of_the_website_you_are_looking_for' );
```

And the you will use $website_information according to what you want and what information is on that variable.